# SQL Server Binary File Storage

Tags: sql-server, database, data-storage

For a quick background, I have an app that I currently support which runs on Oracle 10.2 with dedicated DBAs. In the past when I've wanted to create a table that would store binary data (BLOB in their world - this could be PDFs, DOCX, etc.), the DBAs would always "partition" the data storage of that column/table (not sure which) to a separate physical area on disk. Their reasoning behind this was it helped ensure performance wasn't impacted by having a large number of binary files stored in the same file as the rest of the data where lookups occurred.

My question is whether or not I should do something similar to this for SQL Server (2012, though I doubt the version matters)? If so, how might I go about it and what is the proper terminology for doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a separate filegroup whose file(s) are on a different volume, and then explicitly create the tables that store your LOB data on that filegroup. Filegroup designation is part of the [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) and [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) statements, the default being the PRIMARY filegroup.

You also have different choices for storing files in SQL Server, in 2008+ you can use [FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) (see also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)) and in 2012 you can use [FILETABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx). However in most cases I've had a hard time justifying storing the file in the database; it's often less problematic to store the file on the file system and a pointer in the database.

And you can read my dated and long-winded opinions in [this FAQ article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216014146/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-store-images-in-the-database-or-the-filesystem.html) I wrote 12 years ago.

Keeping in mind that some technology has changed (obviously FILESTREAM and FILETABLE weren't available then), some of the points there remain relevant...

And finally, some [advice on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087.aspx) about file / filegroup handling that might be useful reading.

Comment: If I'm on a VM does it make a difference? I do have separate disk volumes, but being on a VM I'm not sure how much that matters. Regardless of the answer, I'll definitely read up on what you posted though - thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: VM or not, the bottleneck is almost certainly going to be the I/O subsystem. A VM can make use of fast I/O just like a physical machine can. Of course there is always the potential that the virtualization layer, depending on VM technology and software/drivers provided by the I/O vendor, as well as the configuration of the VM and the I/O, can be a tricky set of variables to configure correctly...